# list directory in PHP hide extension

Tags: php, directory, directory-listing

I have been searching for a way to hide an extension which appears from the directory list. I am showing these directory in a website menu but I would like all files to appear with their extension next to the file name. For example file.pdf and file.png.

I need to hide the extension from these files to appear as ( file , file , img , etc..).

php code:

```
<?php
    $path = "./outgoing/";
    function createDir($path = '.')
    {   
        if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
        {
            echo "<ul>";        
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
            {
                if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file !='..')
                    printSubDir($file, $path, $queue);
                else if ($file != '.' && $file !='..')
                    $queue[] = $file;
            }           
            printQueue($queue, $path);
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }

    function printQueue($queue, $path)
    {
        foreach ($queue as $file) 
        {
            printFile($file, $path);
        } 
    }

    function printFile($file, $path)
    {
        echo "<li><a href=\"".$path.$file."\">$file</a></li>";
    }

    function printSubDir($dir, $path)
    {
        echo "<li><span class=\"toggle\">$dir</span>";
        createDir($path.$dir."/",".pdf");
        echo "</li>";
    }
    createDir($path);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to remove ext

```
$temp = explode(".", $file);
$par = $temp[0];
```

Comment: where to put it in code please ?? i used it but gives me an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in/php/index.php on line 137

Comment: Place it wherever you need to show file without extension. It's strange it's complaining about the syntax, check out my update of the post. If you have multiple files use array to store the values and present them on the page later.